# Run bash script with multiple arguments in parallel on multiple hosts

Tags: ssh, bash, copssh

Actually I want to execute my below bash script simultaneously on multiple hosts,i tried pssh command for this:

```
pssh -h hosts.txt -i -I < myscript arg1 arg2 arg3
```

but its not executing, so plz tell me the proper way to execute this...

Answer (score 2):

GNU Parallel has a special mode for this: `--onall`:

```
parallel --slf hosts.txt --onall myscript.sh ::: arg1 arg2 arg3
```

This will run on all machines:

```
myscript.sh arg1
myscript.sh arg2
myscript.sh arg3
```

If you do not want the arguments to change you can use `--nonall`:

```
parallel --slf hosts.txt --nonall myscript.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

which will run:

```
myscript.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

on all machines. Use -j to adjust how many machines you want to log into in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

`cat hosts.txt | parallel ssh {} "'bash -s' < ./myscript.sh arg1 arg2 arg3"`

Comment: Sorry, i test my answers before posting. It works like a charm. Maybe you should try to install it first? :) `apt-get install parallel` or something like that